# How to display multiple selection in Select2 jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

My DB stored information in String like this `Administrator,Anna`, So if I want to display in Select2 this pre-selection, as I know it is must in Array (Sorry if I am wrong). The problem, I need to split it into Array and display.

Unfortunately, both of the names are not being displayed.

[image]

Both of the names already being split in Array.

[image]

It appears when the name just is single like this.

[image]

So how to fix it?

**JS**:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response){
            if (response.status == "Success"){
                $("#editLayer3ActivityOwner").val(response.data[0]["task_owner"]).attr("disabled",false);

                $(response.data).each(function(key,value){
                    var owners = value.task_owner.split(',');
                    $(owners).each(function(k,v){
                        $("#editLayer3ActivityOwner").append($("<option>", {
                            response: v,
                            text: v
                        }));
                    });
                    console.log(owners);
                    $("#editLayer3ActivityOwner").select2();
                });
            }
            else {}       
    },
    error: function(e){}
});
```

Comment: Hey can you create a js fiddle or stackblitz for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$("#sel").val(["Administrator","Anna"]).change();` method. 
i think you are getting response in the same format.so you can give response directly as `$("#editLayer3ActivityOwner").val(response.data).change();`

```js
$("#editLayer3ActivityOwner").select2({ width: '100%', placeholder: "Choose", allowClear: true });

var response=["Administrator","Anna"]; //Hope you are getting the ajax response as this
 $("#editLayer3ActivityOwner").val(response).change();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="editLayer3ActivityOwner" multiple name="editLayer3ActivityOwner">

<option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
<option value="Anna">Anna</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi may I know why the data seems duplicate after I close the modal and reopen back?

Comment: @mastersuse You want to clear all selections? if so use `$("#editLayer3ActivityOwner").val('').trigger('change') ;`

Comment: you `tick` solution is working fine, when I open model, pre-selected value is appear in the box as your Snippet, but I try after that by close the modal without submit or refresh page, then I try to open back the same modal. the pre-selected value is duplicated, 2x. why this happen?